# What is the cleanest way to load reusable data from repositorium?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I had menubar in symfony which is loaded to each site in my project. Normally i load data like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("", name="main")
 * 
 * 
 */
public function main()
{
    $category_rep = $_om->getRepository(Category::class);
    $this->categories = $category_rep->findAll();
    ....
}
```

It's fine, but I am looking to better solution to load data to whole controller or project. I found solution to autoload data by:

```
@Entity("category", expr="repository.find($id)")
public function index(Category $category)
```

but It's can give me only one result from Category Entity (in menubar I wanna show all categories in repositorium). The second idea was make constructor in controller which load this data like this:

```
private $categories;

public function __construct(ObjectManager $_om)
{
    $category_rep = $_om->getRepository(Category::class);
    $this->categories = $category_rep->findAll();

}
```

or make service which will be load that data and run this service in every method. I wanna ask which one of this ideas are the best ('the cleanest') solution. Maybe it's another better option??

Thanks for help,
kris

Comment: If you want to show the categories in a menu bar, why do you need all of the categories to `whole controller or project`? Isn't it enough to have it in the controller action that builds the menu? btw how are you building your menu? Can you paste some code for that?

Comment: I had base.html.twig file where I had main template with css and html which don't change ( the same for each site in project and it didn't have controller method) and I load data from others templates by twig block:  {% block body %}{% endblock %}. Hmm but it's idea to make controller for base template and there load that data... I am so stupid :(

Comment: The code of base in shortcut looks like: `<div class="main-cointainer" ><div class="menubar"></div> <div class="content">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>   </div> ` and I load content by using '{% extends 'base.html.twig' %} {% block content %}{% endblock %}{% block content %}my content{% endblock %}  '

Comment: Thanks for the code examples. And don't be so hard on yourself, nobody is born with that knowledge ;) And if my first comment sounded a bit condescending - I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another, also simple, but much more elegant (imho) would be to create a [custom Twig Function](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html), like so:

```php
class MenuExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    private $categories;

    public function __construct(CategoryRepository $categories)
    {
        $this->categories = $categories;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction(
                'main_menu',
                [$this, 'mainMenu'],
                ['needs_environment' => true]
            ),
        ];
    }

    public function mainMenu(\Twig_Environment $environment)
    {
        $categories = $this->categories->findAll();

        return $environment->render('menu/main.html.twig', [
            'categories' => $categories,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Of course you also need the template for the menu itself, like in previous answer:

```
# menu/main.html.twig

{% for category in categories %}
    <div>
        <a href="{{ path('/url/to/view/category/with/id', { id: category.id }) }}">
            {{ category.name }}
        </a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now you can use the custom function in your `base.html.twig`:

```
<div class="menubar">
    {{ main_menu() }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be a separate controller action to get the categories for the menu, something like:

```php
class MenuController extends AbstractController
{    
    public function displayMainMenu()
    {
        $categories = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Category::class)->findAll();

        return $this->render('menu/main.html.twig', [
            'categories' => $categories,
        ]);
    }
}
```

which would return a partial template with just the menu HTML in it, something like so:

```
# menu/main.html.twig

{% for category in categories %}
    <div>
        <a href="{{ path('/url/to/view/category/with/id', { id: category.id }) }}">
            {{ category.name }}
        </a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now you only need to include that rendered template in your `base.html.twig` by [embedding the controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html):

```
<div class="menubar">
    {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\MenuController\\displayMainMenu')) }}
</div>
```

For more advanced menus you might consider using a dedicated bundle, like the [KnpMenuBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot... I didn't think about make it by this way